# need help editing a url for ImportHTML formula

Tags: url-parameters

I recently began working with import.io to scrape various websites for data I use in researching stocks.  I created an API that pulls 5 yrs of financial data from ADVFN.com  I then used the export function within import.io to integrate the API I created with google sheets.  It works great.  However, what I would like to do is be able to edit the path in the formula so that I can use the API to call up the same data for any stock symbol I enter in Sheet1,cell B1 in my spreadsheet.  Below is the formula.  The stock symbol here is ATW. As you can see you need to specify the exchange in the path as well (in this case it's the NYSE).  I want to be able to edit this so that I can enter a stock symbol in cell B1 on my spreadsheet and it will search for that symbol and return the data.  Any assistance here would be appreciated.  Thanks!

=ImportHtml("https://api.import.io/store/data/a5816419-a232-440d-92c8-09bf989ccbca/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.advfn.com%2Fstock-market%2FNYSE%2FATW%2Ffinancials%3Fbtn%3Dstart_date%26start_date%3D11%26mode%3Dannual_reports&format=HTML&_user=102fe4dc-b403-423f-89a4-e16151128d92&_apikey=102fe4dcb403423f89a4e16151128d92f6bf183ba6b6e3907e836234a054aef23b1c51201a53e1e8336367c8282bafcabffbdbcf85b0d9de2f0769008b04cf99e0fa46179a9279f4d82bbfebf8b3a660", "table", 1)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one way to do it.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X6rW7tn1hOR5HmS_1J9-nu-3humnA5jRVvdkvK2M3oA/edit#gid=0)

Enter the stock symbol in cell B1. It creates the URL in cell C1 and the import function is in cell A2.

The formula in A2 would be

```
=ImportHtml(C1, "table", 1)
```

and the formula in C1 would be

```
 ="https://api.import.io/store/data/a5816419-a232-440d-92c8-09bf989ccbca/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.advfn.com%2Fstock-market%2FNYSE%2F"&$B$1&"%2Ffinancials%3Fbtn%3Dstart_date%26start_date%3D11%26mode%3Dannual_reports&format=HTML&_user=102fe4dc-b403-423f-89a4-e16151128d92&_apikey=102fe4dcb403423f89a4e16151128d92f6bf183ba6b6e3907e836234a054aef23b1c51201a53e1e8336367c8282bafcabffbdbcf85b0d9de2f0769008b04cf99e0fa46179a9279f4d82bbfebf8b3a660"
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I did try something like what you have here but it doesn't seem to work right.  You used AAPL in your example and it did return the correct data (2004 financials).  However, if you try other tickers like CBI or GILD it won't return the correct data (different years?).  The only other variable in the path as far as I can tell is the exchange the company is on (NYSE, NASDAQ). I was thinking maybe that had something to do with the formula returning the wrong data.  The thing is though CBI is on the NYSE (same as ATW) but it still doesn't return the right data?

Comment: sorry, CBI will return the correct data (NYSE) but GILD won't (NASDAQ)

Comment: I put GILD in & things seem to work (it's in the example) but on tab 2 APPL stopped working . . .  error seems to go back to the URL from [https://api.import.io/store/data/a5816419-a232-440d-92c8-09bf989ccbca/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.advfn.com%2Fstock-market%2FNYSE%2FAPPL%2Ffinancials%3Fbtn%3Dstart_date%26start_date%3D11%26mode%3Dannual_reports&format=HTML&_user=102fe4dc-b403-423f-89a4-e16151128d92&_apikey=102fe4dcb403423f89a4e16151128d92f6bf183ba6b6e3907e836234a054aef23b1c51201a53e1e8336367c8282bafcabffbdbcf85b0d9de2f0769008b04cf99e0fa46179a9279f4d82bbfebf8b3a660](import.io.)